# Preg_match inside a loop issue

Tags: php, logging, preg-match

I'm trying to do a `preg_match` on an array of strings using a for loop but it's only returning the filtered result for the final item in the array.

Here is my code:

`<!-- language: lang-php -->`

```
$file = "smalllog";
$handle = fopen($file, 'rb');   
if ($handle) {  
    $lines = array();
    $count = 0;
    while ( ($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        if(strpbrk($line,"/tracking/p2x/")) {               
            $lines[$count]['string'] = $line;               
            $count++;
        }               
    }
    fclose($handle);    
}   
for($i=0;$i<count($lines);$i++) {   
    $matches = array(); 
    preg_match("/^(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) \[([^:]+):(\d+:\d+:\d+) ([^\]]+)\] \"(\S+) (.*?) (\S+)\" (\S+) (\S+) (\".*?\") (\".*?\")$/", $lines[$i]['string'], $matches);
    print_r($matches);      
    print '<br /><br />';   
}
```

Which should display a list of exploded arrays.  However what i actually see looks more like this:

`Array()`

`Array()`

`Array ( !--correctly exploded data in here--! )`

I apologize if this is a dumb question - my PHP skills are not great.

**EDIT:** Here is the change that seems to have corrected the issue:

Changing the regexp from:

```
"/^(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) \[([^:]+):(\d+:\d+:\d+) ([^\]]+)\] \"(\S+) (.*?) (\S+)\" (\S+) (\S+) (\".*?\") (\".*?\")$/"
```

to:

```
"/^(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) \[([^:]+):(\d+:\d+:\d+) ([^\]]+)\] \"(\S+) (.*?) (\S+)\" (\S+) (\S+) (\".*?\") (\".*?\")/"
```

(dropped the `$`)

Comment: `$preg_match` will only return one result, use `$preg_match_all` to return multiple

Comment: Obviously the pattern doesn't match the lines in your file except the last line can you post a few lines from your file?

Comment: At the moment I'm using 3 preset strings to test with.  Regardless of their order, only the final entry returns correctly.  I've been able to verify it working with each distinct value in that final position.

Comment: Just before your for loop do a var_dump( $lines ) see if it contains what it is supposed to contain.

Comment: Yup, i've verified that the values assigned to $lines are all correct.  I was also tracing them out immediately before preg_match was called to doublecheck.

Comment: remove the $ sign from the end of your pattern see if that makes any change.

Comment: I think you nailed it.  This regexp seems to be parsing things correctly.  `"/^(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) \[([^:]+):(\d+:\d+:\d+) ([^\]]+)\] \"(\S+) (.*?) (\S+)\" (\S+) (\S+) (\".*?\") (\".*?\")/"`  Thanks a ton for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[$preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) is what you want

```
$file = "smalllog";
$handle = fopen($file, 'rb');   
if ($handle) {  
    $lines = array();
    $count = 0;
    while ( ($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        if(strpbrk($line,"/tracking/p2x/")) {               
            $lines[$count]['string'] = $line;               
            $count++;
        }               
    }
    fclose($handle);    
}   
for($i=0;$i<count($lines);$i++) {   
    $matches = array(); 
    preg_match_all("/^(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) \[([^:]+):(\d+:\d+:\d+) ([^\]]+)\] \"(\S+) (.*?) (\S+)\" (\S+) (\S+) (\".*?\") (\".*?\")$/", $lines[$i]['string'], $matches);
    print_r($matches);      
    print '<br /><br />';   
}
```

Comment: with preg_match_all i get the same basic issue except the first two returned matches are now sets of empty arrays instead of single empty arrays.  It looks like:
Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) [2] => Array ( ) [3] => Array ( ) [4] => Array ( ) [5] => Array ( ) [6] => Array ( ) [7] => Array ( ) [8] => Array ( ) [9] => Array ( ) [10] => Array ( ) [11] => Array ( ) [12] => Array ( ) [13] => Array ( ) ) 
Array(!----Correctly exploded values------!)

Comment: see what happens when you comment out `$matches = array();`

Comment: no dice :(
Interesting to note, that when i do individual preg_matches for anything other than the last index it also fails.  For example `preg_match("/^(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) \[([^:]+):(\d+:\d+:\d+) ([^\]]+)\] \"(\S+) (.*?) (\S+)\" (\S+) (\S+) (\".*?\") (\".*?\")$/", $lines[0]['string'], $matches);`  Also returns an empty array.  It even fails if all 3 values in the array are identical.

Comment: ok just a couple of notes, `preg_match_all` returns an array so you don't need to create it every time in the for loop. Also, your using `print_r($matches)` every time the loop is run, so this may in fact be the reason why only the last one succeeds, place the `print_r($matches)` outside the loop along with commenting out the `$matches = array()`

Comment: I'm not sure how to pass preg_match_all multiple subject strings without looping through the array.  I've adjusted the code to look like this:  `for($i=0;$i<count($lines);$i++) { 
 print $lines[$i].'<br /><br />';
 preg_match_all("/^(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) \[([^:]+):(\d+:\d+:\d+) ([^\]]+)\] \"(\S+) (.*?) (\S+)\" (\S+) (\S+) (\".*?\") (\".*?\")$/s", $lines[$i], $matches,PREG_SET_ORDER); 
}
print_r($matches);`  But the issue unfortunately remains.

Comment: try this `$arr=array();for($i=0;$i<count($lines);$i++) {print $lines[$i].'<br /><br />'; preg_match_all("/^(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) \[([^:]+):(\d+:\d+:\d+) ([^\]]+)\] \"(\S+) (.*?) (\S+)\" (\S+) (\S+) (\".*?\") (\".*?\")$/s", $lines[$i], $matches,PREG_SET_ORDER); array_push($matches, $arr[i]); } print_r($arr);`

Comment: I believe the suggestion above about removing the $ from the regexp pattern has corrected the issue.  Appreciate the help though :)

Comment: aha, glad to hear it. I'm actually going through a similar issue today with my code. I found this site here: http://txt2re.com/ incredibly useful for the regex.

Comment: Wow that site is fantastic - I am terrible with regexp.  Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

You are using [**strpbrk()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpbrk.php) completely wrong strpbrk expects its second argument to be a **character list**, you are obviously trying to search for a string with it. Use **strpos()** for that.

Comment: Thank you, I've made the change, however it does not seem to impact the issue at hand.

Answer (score 0):

You have \n character at the end of your lines (except the last line) and since normal .* doesn't match \n your pattern doesn't match. You need to use the DOTALL modifier, add "s" to the end of your pattern (after the delimiter) and you should be fine:

```
"/^(\S+) ... (\".*?\")$/s"
```

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. My Loop now looks like this:  `for($i=0;$i<count($lines);$i++) { 
 print $lines[$i]['string'].'<br /><br />';
 preg_match("/^(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) \[([^:]+):(\d+:\d+:\d+) ([^\]]+)\] \"(\S+) (.*?) (\S+)\" (\S+) (\S+) (\".*?\") (\".*?\")$/s", $lines[$i]['string'], $matches);
 print_r($matches);  
 print '<br /><br />'; 
}`

But still getting the same problem.  Considering I've verified all other aspects to be functioning, my hunch is that the issue does lie somewhere in the regexp.  Unfortunately my knowledge of regexp is appallingly bad.I'm having trouble narrowing it down.

Comment: @dmckenna if you don't post those 3 lines you are trying to match it would be very hard to guess where the problem lies.

Comment: I think your suggestion about removing the $ from the pattern has fixed it.  Thanks again for your help, I really appreciate it.